# "The command syntax is incorrect." Using a copy command in a Jenkins pipelinepipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using a bat copy of a file to another directory, but it tells me that the command syntax is wrong, I've tried many options, with quotes, without quotation marks. The answer you give me is syntax error in the command. This is the command:

```
post { 
            always { 
                echo 'Copy Reports'
                publishHTML([
                    allowMissing: false, 
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, 
                    keepAll: false, 
                    reportDir: 'target/newman', 
                    reportFiles: 'report.html', 
                    reportName: 'Postman Report', 
                    reportTitles: ''
                ])
                bat '''
                    copy target/newman/report.html C:\\server\\test\\%JOB_BASE_NAME%\\report_%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%\\report_%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%.html
                    copy target/newman/report.json C:\\server\\test\\%JOB_BASE_NAME%\\report_%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%\\report_%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%.json
                '''
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
bat script: '''

'''
```

otherwise the exact error message would help

Comment: Now I got this issue:

`C:\Users\BK71005\.jenkins\workspace\test-fpe-pensionplans>copy target/newman/report.json C:/server/test/test-fpe-pensionplans/report_2019-10-01/report_ 8:48:51.json `

The system cannot find the specified driver.

Comment: looks like on parameter  TIME is null an the result is a broken path